# "El segurata se comió un bocata junto a la fogata." ¿Qué significado tiene el sufijo "-ata"?

Tags: significado, españa, sufijos

Aunque expresiones como *segurata* (de "encargado de seguridad") o *drogata* ("que consume drogas") parezcan modernas (sin entrar en si tienen o no una connotación peyorativa), en realidad estas construcciones con el sufijo **-ata** se llevan usando desde hace tiempo. Si bien *[bocata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iqjrnZ)* (de "bocadillo") apareció en el DRAE en su versión de 1992, palabras como *[fogata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I9Bde8P)* (de "fuego") o *[culata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bcey6wy)* (de "culo") llevan en el diccionario desde el principio de los tiempos (es decir, de los tiempos del diccionario, desde la versión de 1780).

El sufijo -ata, ¿tiene en todos estos ejemplos el mismo significado? Y en caso afirmativo, ¿cuál es ese significado?

Comment: Pues resulta que la RAE tiene una entrada para [-ata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4GZKKGk) en la que vemos cinco acepciones distintas con sendas denotaciones.

Comment: @fedorqui ni se me había ocurrido buscar el significado del sufijo en el DRAE. Sin embargo, ninguna de las acepciones (cargo, institución, acción/efecto, cría o cualidad) me cuadra para _bocata_, por ejemplo. En los casos de _segurata_ o _drogata_ ¿podría ser un uso de la acepción de "cargo" con una corrupción en sentido peyorativo?

Comment: Mmm buscando [bocata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iqjrnZ) veo que hablan del _sufijo jergal -ata_.

Comment: Os dejo un enlace con una discusión del tema que parece que aporta ideas interesantes:
https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discusión:-ata

Comment: @JulioCodesal interesante discusión. Al parecer, [_keniata_](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/gentilicio-de-kenia-1449/) no sería una construcción por sufijo sino que... _surgida probablemente del apellido de Yomo Kenyatta o Keniata, líder de la independencia y primer presidente del país_

Comment: A veces la palabra tabú _nigger_ se traduce como _negrata_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siguiendo [las pistas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17342/el-segurata-se-comi%C3%B3-un-bocata-junto-a-la-fogata-qu%C3%A9-significado-tiene-el-su/17344?noredirect=1#comment23491_17342) de [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui), llego a la siguiente respuesta:

El sufijo -ata en *bocata*, *drogata* y *segurata* es un **sufijo jergal**, explicado en la gramática en el [epígrafe 6.11n](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UnZJHofRdCyUgrCw):

> En la lengua juvenil del español europeo se documentan algunas formaciones con los sufijos **-ota, -eta y -ata**, a menudo de sentido despectivo [...]

Cita como ejemplos *drogota*, *fumeta*, *pasota*, aunque también *sociata* y *segurata*. En esta categoría también entrarían *bocata*, *tocata*, *cubata* y otros que, [como apunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17342/el-segurata-se-comi%C3%B3-un-bocata-junto-a-la-fogata-qu%C3%A9-significado-tiene-el-su/17344?noredirect=1#comment23499_17344) [cdlvcdlv](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12991/cdlvcdlv), se alejan del sentido peyorativo e introducen un sentido de cercanía o incluso de hacer al hablante más [molón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pas89at%7CPau6gh0). Curiosamente, la palabra *[bocata](http://elpais.com/elpais/2014/03/06/eps/1394133801_099349.html)* fue al parecer invención del gran [Forges](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forges):

> ¿Y los sufijos en –ata?: *bocata, cubata, tocata, segurata*... Las tres primeras han entrado en el Diccionario, donde se anota esa formación con el sufijo jergal –ata. Forges aclara: “*Bocata* sí que lo inventé yo, y *tocata* también. Pero *cubata* y *segurata*, no”. Esa manera de llamar al bocadillo, al cubalibre, al tocadiscos y al vigilante parte de los propios recursos del idioma, los mismos que nos dan “caminata” o “perorata”, aunque tal vez un poco dislocados para la ocasión, como sucede con *estupendérrimo*.

En los casos de *fogata* y *culata*, se aplica lo dicho en la RAE para el [sufijo -ata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4GZKKGk): *fogata* sería el efecto del fuego, y *culata* (aunque no es un adjetivo) sería la cualidad de "ser el culo", aunque en este caso la palabra vino del italiano ya así.

Comment: ¡Qué curioso! Para el artículo de bocata también puede ser válido el enlace a [este artículo de El País Semanal](http://elpais.com/elpais/2014/03/06/eps/1394133801_099349.html). ¿Sabías, por cierto, que _Forges_ se "llama" así porque su apellido Fraguas se dice _alforges_ en catalán y decidió adaptarlo?

Comment: @fedorqui casi que mejor uso tu enlace, gracias por el apunte. Lo de Forges lo acabo de aprender en la Wikipedia :)

Comment: Iba a añadirlo como comentario a la pregunta, pero lo pongo aquí mejor, ya que hay respuesta y además va en ese sentido. No todas las etimologías son rastreables, aparte de porque no hay documentación de todas las palabras, porque a veces los hablantes deforman las palabras por instinto (algo tiene que ver con el "genio del idioma", que dice Álex Grijelmo) para causar ciertas impresiones. Pasa también a la hora de darle nombre a un niño. No creo que mucha gente cuya lengua madre no sea el inglés entienda la gracia de [**esto**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMSCPSJXAEg). (cont.)

Comment: También encontré la connotación despectiva de -ata en el libro "Morfología léxica: la formación de las palabras" de Soledad Varela Ortega; pone como ejemplos _chivata_, _niñata_ y _cegata_. Desde este efecto de menosprecio (como en _segurata_) se llega fácilmente a otro cercano, el de quitar formalidad a la denominación (y por ahí va lo de _jergal_, creo yo) y servir de aglutinador de un grupo: los _carrozas_ ponen el tocadiscos, pero nosotros ponemos en el _tocata_ música que _mola_.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv: Interesante comentario. Desde luego, la connotación es, como dice la gramática, **a menudo** despectiva, pero no siempre. Me resulta curioso ver cómo en el caso en que no lo es le da un sentido de cercanía e incluso como de _molón_ al término o al que habla: bocata más _guay_ que bocadillo, tocata más _cool_ que tocadiscos, etc.

Comment: Estaba editando el comentario anterior para añadir eso mismo de la cercanía, me han interrumpido y se me han pasado los cinco minutos. Pienso lo mismo. La conclusión que quería sacar, uniendo los dos comentarios anteriores, es que para la mayoría de los hablantes lo esencial es el impacto que tiene en los demás las palabras que usan, más que la precisión en su etimología. Si me suena "cuba-libre" algo estirado, lo deformo hasta _cubata_, que sí me suena bien, y poco me importa si el sufijo es coherente con los usos anteriores. A Forges la deformación "bocata" le sonó más graciosa que otras...

Comment: ... y no hay reconocimiento más manifiesto que el éxito que ha tenido. Creo que, a veces, la búsqueda de una etimología es vana y las explicaciones forzadas. El idioma cambia porque genios (a veces malignos) producen mutaciones mejor adaptadas al genio del idioma. Y lo que empieza siendo jerga o un chiste, se trasfunde entre los hablantes hasta que forma parte del acervo lingüístico.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv desde luego, en muchas ocasiones será así, que la deformación se haga por producir un impacto. Curiosamente, en otra entrevista Forges asegura que, simplemente, cuando fue a escribir la palabra "bocadillo" en el [bocadillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iV6kp0), vio que no le iba a entrar y acortó a "bocata". En cambio, estoy seguro de que el mismo Forges se inventó [muslamen](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q9Y4iZK) para causar un impacto. Un genio sin duda.