# ¿Cómo formar un despectivo?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, sufijos

Estaba leyendo acerca de **sufijos despectivos**...

> Normalmente, cada palabra cuenta con su “forma despectiva” propia, o lo que es lo mismo, a cada palabra le corresponde un afijo particular con el que formar su despectivo. Ciertas palabras, y estas palabras son la excepción, admiten en cambio más de un afijo con el que formar el despectivo.

Lee todo en: Despectivo | [La guía de Lengua](http://lengua.laguia2000.com/gramatica/despectivo#ixzz4EmMVjZjO)

Algunas palabras derivadas se encuentran en el RAE, como padrastro, mujerzuela, libraco, etc. pero si quiero formar nueva derivación de una palabra con despectivo, por ejemplo...

- flaca – a + "ucha" = *flacucha*
- casa – a + "ucha" = *casucha*

Entonces, ¿puedo decir de "finca", *fincucha*?

- padre – e + "astro" = *padrastro*
- madre – e + "astra" = *madrastra*

Entonces, de "sastre", ¿por qué no *sastrastro*?

"Pueblo" según DRAE es derivada como [populacho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TfU7BGX), pero en nuestro dialecto decimos *pueblucho*.

¿Hay guía, sistema o procedimiento alguno predeterminado para agregar un sufijo despectivo apropiado? ¿O toda palabra lleva su propio sufijo despectivo determinado solamente por intuición o costumbre regional?

Disculpen, pero mi lengua materna no es el español, y no tengo dicha intuición.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish Language](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/)! No está mal para ser tu primera pregunta, bien planteada y mejor redactada, ¡nadie diría que el español no es tu primera lengua!

Comment: _Populacho_ es derivado de "pueblo" en su sentido de conjunto de personas, mientras que _pueblucho_ lo es en el sentido de poblado o aldea.

Comment: Ojo: *padrastro* y *madrastra* tienen también el significado de padre o madre adoptivos, sin ser esto necesariamente despectivo.

Answer (score 8):

He estado repasando el capítulo 9 de la [Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica), dedicado a la derivación apreciativa, y en especial el apartado 9.7: *[Sufijos aumentativos y despectivos](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QnvgZAibRSdbHXxj)*. Lo más que he encontrado son listas de posibles sufijos con los que formar las variantes despectivas. Simplemente un apunte: no existen los despectivos formados mediante los sufijos *-zuelo* o *-zuela*, sino los formados con **-uelo** o **-uela**. Ejemplos:

- Paño >> *Pañuelo*
- Hoja >> *Hojuela*

A veces, para añadir un sufijo se añaden además interfijos, como es el caso de:

- Nube >> *Nubarrón (nub-arr-ón)*
- Bicho >> *Bicharraco (bich-arr-aco)*

De ahí palabras como el *hombrezuelo* que viene en la página de ejemplo que enlazas.

Sin embargo, y volviendo al quid de la pregunta, no he encontrado nada al respecto de qué sufijos usar en cada caso. Hay algunas ocasiones en las que las palabras ya están formadas y se usa la forma a la que ya tenemos hecho el oído, sin pararnos a buscar otras. Algunas, como comentas, están en el diccionario porque la palabra que incluye el sufijo tiene lo que se denomina un "significado opaco". Se entiende esto como lo contrario de transparente, que significa que el significado de la palabra más el sufijo se obtiene directamente:

- Casa >> *Casita (casa pequeña)*

No es necesario una entrada aparte. Pero sí por ejemplo para:

- Cintura >> *[Cinturón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Hp6AkT) (no es una cintura grande)*

Estos ejemplos han sido construidos con sufijos aumentativos o diminutivos, pero también sucede con los sufijos despectivos:

- Flaco >> *Flacucho (despectivo de flaco sin más, no está en el diccionario)*
- Padre >> *[Padrastro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RQdBfrY) (tiene otros significados aparte del de "mal padre", luego tiene entrada propia en el diccionario)*

En el caso de palabras a las que quieras añadir un sufijo despectivo y no haya ya uno que sea de uso común, como podría ser el caso de *sastre* que propones, pues entonces es cuestión de probar a ver cuál es el que mejor suena. Tú mismo te has dado cuenta de que *sastrastro* suena horrible y es complicado de pronunciar. De las opciones que da la RAE, y por proximidad con (precisamente) *hombrezuelo*, yo diría ***sastrezuelo***. Nótese además que ya existen variantes conocidas como *sastrecillo*, por lo que dicha proximidad hace que la forma despectiva suene mejor.

Así que para formar otros derivados, pues simplemente escoge la que mejor suene: *mueblucho*, *portatilucho*, *sillastra*, *relojacho*, *libraco*, *bolsorro*, ***fincuela***. Siéntete libre de improvisar, la lengua se trata precisamente de eso. Gracias a este tipo de improvisaciones tenemos palabras como *bocata*, que el otro día salió al caso [en otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17342/12637).

Comment: Muy interesante. Sólo una pequeña aclaración: el despectivo de casa es casucha y no casita, que viene siendo el diminutivo.

Comment: @VladimirNu en ese ejemplo precisamente no pretendía construir un despectivo, sino ilustrar lo que es un derivado de significado transparente. Del mismo modo, _cinturón_ tampoco es un despectivo, sino un ejemplo de derivado con significado opaco.

Comment: @VladimirNu he incluido esa aclaración en la respuesta y añadidos más ejemplos con despectivos.

Comment: Qué triste el uso de los despectivos. Yo los uso poco. Siento que es mejor connotar al sustantivo tal cual es o usando algún diminutivo.