# Tecnicismos: ¿Dónde está el límite entre lo correcto y lo incorrecto?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Tengo una duda recurrente, que me surge a menudo en temas relacionados con mi profesión, que es la ingeniería, y que me imagino que en otras disciplinas también sucederá. En mi día a día debo emplear bastantes tecnicismos, y es muy habitual que la palabra que suele usar la gente no esté recogida en el diccionario de la RAE, por lo que a veces es difícil saber cuál es la palabra más adecuada que se debe emplear.

En algunos casos, estos tecnicismos no son más que traducciones directas del inglés, y suelen tener una alternativa en español que no se usa debido a la popularidad que alcanza la primera. Esta situación para mi es fácil de resolver, y siempre que soy consciente utilizo la opción española, ya que no está justificado el uso de la otra si se desea hablar correctamente.

---

Existen otros casos de palabras que no existen en la RAE pero creo que sí que se deberían dar por correctos, como es el caso de los tecnicismos de la ciencia de los materiales, como [Martensita](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martensita) o [Austenita](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austenita).

Sin embargo, en muchas ocasiones es difícil saber si la palabra técnica que se está usando es correcta o si existe una alternativa. Estos días me surgió esta duda con la palabra que se debe usar para referirse a la acción de cambiar de tamaño una imagen. En internet son muy populares las palabras *redimensionar* y *reescalar*. Además, múltiples programas informáticos también las emplean, pero ninguna figura en el diccionario de la RAE. En inglés, por ejemplo, sí que existe la palabra [resize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/resize) para designar a esta acción.

---

Me da la sensación de que no existe un criterio unificado, cuando se emplean estas palabras, en cuanto a cuál es la mejor opción si se desea escribir correctamente.

Me gustaría saber la opinión de otra gente y si realmente sí que existe alguna herramienta para resolver este tipo de conflictos

Answer (score 9):

Sí que es cierto que en muchas ocasiones los tecnicismos no vienen reflejados en el DRAE, pero para eso existen los diccionarios técnicos. Yo trabajo de informático y he hecho software para diversos sectores, desde la sanidad hasta el naval, y en este último hay una cantidad de vocabulario técnico increíble, que no suele venir reflejado en diccionarios corrientes o, si vienen reflejado, no suele ser con la acepción específica del sector.

En cuanto a términos más corrientes, como el que propones de *resize*, sí que es cierto que el DRAE no recoge el término *redimensionar*, pero sí que recoge por un lado *[dimensionar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DnCIBKL)* (determinar las dimensiones de algo) y por otro *[re-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFxyLmQ)* (significa 'repetición'). El hecho de que *redimensionar* no venga en el DRAE es porque es un término de significado transparente. Puedes ver más sobre términos de significado opaco o transparente en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17451/12637) a otra pregunta. Resumiendo, los términos que se construyen con prefijos o sufijos añadidos a otros términos, y cuyo significado es obvio conociendo el significado de todas las partes, no entran en el DRAE.

Por tanto, **redimensionar** me parece un término muy correcto para traducir *resize*, ya que significa "volver a determinar las dimensiones de algo" si sumamos los significados de las partes.

Answer (score 4):

One option for the general case might be to use n-grams to see what use is being made of the terms. I am not sure how Google n-gram viewer works with Spanish verbs but just entering the terms you suggested makes *redimensionar* the clear winner over *reescalar* with *resize* nowhere. I was taught as a child never to use a foreign phrase when there was an English equivalent so I sympathise with your desire to avoid unnecessary anglicisms.

=======
edit: it seems Google n-gram viewer know even less about Spanish verbs than I do so you also have to ask about *redimensionado* and so on to get a full picture.

Comment: Sincerely, I did not know that tool before your post. Thanks a lot for making me aware of it, I will give it a try. However,  a word may be massively wrongly used, due to its popularity, and thus this tool is not really trusty for me.
What I am looking for is a collection of official or at least made by philology professionals dictionary.

Comment: I agree that all it does is tell you what other people do but if we take the view that what careful native speakers do defines what is right then perhaps it is a help.

Comment: @Jalo Another issue with Google N-gram : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer: "The data set has been criticized for its reliance upon inaccurate OCR, an overabundance of scientific literature, and for including large numbers of incorrectly dated and categorized texts.[15][16] Another issue is that the corpus is in effect a library, containing one of each book. A single, prolific author is thereby able to noticeably insert new phrases into the Google Books lexicon, whether the author is widely read or not."

Comment: @user13560 How true, how very true. I suppose a truly scientific approach would download the database and process it oneself and also use other sources.

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de lo largo y formal de tu escrito, podrías agregar una sección para la definición de términos (glosario).  El español es un lenguaje vivo y la RAE publica nuevas palabras aceptadas regularmente.  Estas palabras provienen del uso popular o de la necesidad de incluir nuevos conceptos en nuestro idioma.

Comment: No me sirve esa respuesta, lo siento. El tipo de palabras a las que me refiero muy rara vez se incluyen en la RAE. Fíjate en los 2 primeros ejemplos que te pongo, que son palabras vigentes en la jerga técnica desde hace posiblemente 100 años. La RAE no está enfocada a dar definición a palabras usadas en campos muy concretos. Me imagino que uno de los motivos es que necesitarías una comisión de expertos lingüistas en cada campo para poder realizar esa evaluación

Comment: Te entiendo @Jalo.  En una ocasión presenté un tratado técnico en el que sólo podía utilizar términos incluidos en el diccionario de la RAE vigente.  Fué una gran labor de redacción tener que definir conceptos con descripciones, cuándo en la práctica utilizábamos un término del inglés.  Buena suerte colega.